# Automate text file editing with batch, python, whatever

Tags: python, text, batch-file, automation

I know this  is a simple fix, but can't seem to find an answer for it:

I am trying to create a batch file that takes all files in a folder downloaded daily from an ftp server, combine them into a separate folder, and then make new files out of the combined file based on the column of the file (this is the part giving me trouble).

For example:

We have data come in daily in a format like this:

```
DATE/TIME  | NodeID | Data    
04/05/2013 11:23:11   |     2     |   10    
04/05/2013 11:23:11    |    3  |      10    
04/05/2013 11:23:11    |    4   |     10    
04/05/2013 11:23:11    |    5   |     10    
04/05/2013 11:23:11     |   6    |    10    
04/05/2013 11:23:11      |  7   |     10    
04/06/2013 11:24:12     |   1    |    12    
04/06/2013 11:24:12     |   1    |    12        
04/06/2013 11:24:12    |    4   |     12        
04/06/2013 11:24:12     |   1     |   12        
04/06/2013 11:24:12     |   3   |     12        
04/06/2013 11:24:12     |   2    |    12
```

What I want is to take all the rows with NodeID 1 and put them in a separate file, all the rows with NodeID 2 in a separate file, etc...

I have very limited knowledge in python but am willing to do this in anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't tested it, but this could work:

```
with open('your/file') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        rows = line.split('|')
        with open(rows[1].strip() + '.txt', 'a') as out:
            out.write(line)
        line = file.readline()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciated, also, how could I change the  folder path where the files are written?

Comment: Actually, it seems to be skipping a lot of entries, any ideas?

Comment: I tested it and for me it doesn't seem to skip any entrys.
You can change the target folder if you switch line 5 from

    `with open(rows[1].strip() + '.txt', 'a') as out:`
to:
    `with open('your/target/folder' + rows[1].strip() + '.txt', 'a') as out:` Be aware that the paths are relative to the current working directory and not to te script.

Comment: To the skipping lines: It seems that you're using windows and i use Linux/GNU. Maybe it's something OS-related. Like the meaning of the a mode.

Comment: I actually ended up using the .csv module but this answer got me thinking. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
DEL noderesult*.txt 2>nul
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=1,2*delims=|" %%i IN (logfile.txt) DO (
 SET node=%%j
 SET node=!node: =!
 >>noderesult!node!.txt ECHO(%%i^|%%j^|%%k
)
```

Should do the job, producing `noderesult?.txt` - caution - the `DEL` line deletes all existing `noderesult*.txt`

Comment: Do I save this as a batch file and run it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
f_in = "path_to_your_file"
f = open(f_in,'r')

f_out = {}

for l in f:
  if l != '\n':
    row = l.split('|')
    id = int(row[1])
    if id not in f_out:
      f_out[id] = open(f_in + "_" + str(id),'w')
    f_out[id].write(l)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message:  _ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NodeID'_

Comment: Probably it means that in the NodeID cell of some row you have something different than an integer. Try to debug, for example by printing the content of row[1] in each iteration: `print row[1]`

Comment: You can ommit the integer conversion and replace the conversion for a simple command to remove strange symbols: `id = row[1].strip()`, like in the answer of Ich...